# Styling visited links

Tags: html, css

The second to last link, when clicked, shows its default state which is to turn and remain a dark purple.

```
<div id="footer">
    <p><b>Logged in as:</b> <pre><?php echo showUser(); ?></pre></p>
    <p><b>Tracks rated so far:</b><pre><? echo showRatings(); ?></pre></p>
    <p><b>Withdraw from experiment:</b> <a href="kill_session.php">Click here</a>.</p>
    <p><b>Contact information:</b> <a href="mailto:#">d"""""""""".com</a>.</p>
</div>
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
#footer a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#footer a:hover {
    color: red;
}
#footer a:active {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    color: blue;
}
```

Its only basic, but improves it from the basic style. How can I make the visited link remain blue?

Comment: Either set a color to `#footer a` or `a:visited` to override the user agent stylesheet. Also follow the [*LVHA* order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994383/why-do-alink-visited-hover-active-need-to-be-in-correct-order).

Comment: [Use `#footer a:visited { color: blue }` to specify the text color for visited links](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

Comment: Thanks - I've changed my css and all is okay now :-)  On to my next little niggles!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either set a color on `#footer a`:

```css
#footer a { color: blue }
```

or

Set a color with [`a:visited`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) to override the [user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet):

```css
#footer a:visited { color: blue }
```

Remember to follow the [LVHA order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994383/why-do-alink-visited-hover-active-need-to-be-in-correct-order) (`:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`)

Comment: Thanks - was going to say put it as an answer and I'll accept :-)  Thanks for the link also :-)