# Anchor element doesn't change color when hovered

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following CSS:

```
.container a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(23, 230, 230);
}

.container a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: white;
}

.container a:visited {
    color: rgb(230, 0, 230);
}
```

And this html (piece of):

```
<div class="container">
    ...
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why all the link options work, except for the color on hover: It does get underlined, but the color doesn't change. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with pseudo-classes on anchor elements, ***the order matters***.

They must be in this order:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

> `a:hover` MUST come after `a:link` and `a:visited` in the CSS definition in order to be effective! `a:active` MUST come after `a:hover` in the CSS definition in order to be effective!
>
> *<sub>source: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp</sub>*

There's a popular mnemonic you can use to remember this: LOVE HATE (lv ha).

For more details, see these references:

- [Why do anchor pseudo-classes a:link, :visited, :hover, :active need to be in correct order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16994383/3597276)
- [Why does .foo a:link, .foo a:visited {} selector override a:hover, a:active {} selector in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7371732/3597276)
- [How To Remember The Order of Selectors: LOVE and HATE](https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/)

Comment: Not related to the question but it is a good practice to always include `:focus` in the list (before `:hover`). It is used for keyboard navigation.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle link for everyone](https://jsfiddle.net/1odo0thc/1/)

```
.container a {
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
/* color: rgb(0, 230, 230); */
}

.container a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: green;
}

/* .container a:visited {
    color: rgb(2, 0, 230);/
} */


.test {
  /* color: black; */
}
```

I loaded up your html and CSS into my sublime and it totally works fine.  I toyed around with the colors a bit and everything is great.  I loaded it up in fiddle to show you.  When you have a list like you do, you want to target the list with some sort of class or ID to target them specifically.  I commented some things out inside of the fiddle for you to see. `enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding your css is not taking not taking effect no matter what you do, it's worth adding `!important` parameters to tell the browser you designate your style attribute as having precedence.

```
.container a {
  text-decoration:none !important;
  font-weight: bold !important;
  }
  .container a:visited {
    color: rgb(230, 0, 230) !important;
  }     
  .container a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline !important;
    color: white !important;
  }
```

Having said that, sometimes even with `!important`, still your style may be overridden. To unravel the CSS settings in the browser it's essential to use the inspector console. I think you may already be using the inspector, but if you want more info on this, please let me know.